# Firebase Firestore rule that allows either undefined or max length of 600 characters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to get a rule that will allow a value to not be set at all(undefined) or to pass another test, in this case, a max length of 600 characters.

My current rules are set as follows:

```
function incomingData() {
    return request.resource.data;
}

function hasNotMaxSizeOfDescriptionExceeded() {
 return !incomingData().description || incomingData().description.size() <= 600;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out with the line:

```
!incomingData().keys().hasAll(['description'])
```

You can check if a prop. exists in the incoming collection

Answer (score 0):

In order to check that a property is either undefined or matches another test you could use the `in` operator:

```
function incomingData() {
    return request.resource.data;
}

function hasNotMaxSizeOfDescriptionExceeded() {
 return !('description' in incomingData()) || incomingData().description.size() <= 600;
}
```